# Open JPA Exception with Datasource in WAS 7.0 Java

Tags: java, openjpa

I am getting Exception with Open JPA .

I have created WAS Data Source. Here is My Persistence XML

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">

```
<persistence-unit name="App11" transaction-type="JTA">
<provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
<jta-data-source>java:comp/env/jdbc/mydatasource</jta-data-source>  
     <class>vo.Entity</class>
     <properties>
        <property name="openjpa.TransactionMode" value="managed"/>
                <property name="openjpa.ConnectionFactoryMode" value="managed"/>
    </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

I am getting this exception while executing.

aused by: org.apache.commons.lang.exception.NestableRuntimeException: There was an error duing JNDI lookup of the name "java:comp/env/jdbc/mydatasource".
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.Configurations.lookup(Configurations.java:592)
    at org.apache.openjpa.conf.OpenJPAConfigurationImpl.lookupConnectionFactory(OpenJPAConfigurationImpl.java:966)
    at org.apache.openjpa.conf.OpenJPAConfigurationImpl.getConnectionFactory(OpenJPAConfigurationImpl.java:954)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.conf.JDBCConfigurationImpl.createConnectionFactory(JDBCConfigurationImpl.java:801)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.conf.JDBCConfigurationImpl.getDBDictionaryInstance(JDBCConfigurationImpl.java:568)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.MappingRepository.endConfiguration(MappingRepository.java:1221)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.Configurations.configureInstance(Configurations.java:476)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.Configurations.configureInstance(Configurations.java:401)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.PluginValue.instantiate(PluginValue.java:102)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.ObjectValue.instantiate(ObjectValue.java:82)
    at org.apache.openjpa.conf.OpenJPAConfigurationImpl.newMetaDataRepositoryInstance(OpenJPAConfigurationImpl.java:861)
    at org.apache.openjpa.conf.OpenJPAConfigurationImpl.getMetaDataRepositoryInstance(OpenJPAConfigurationImpl.java:852)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.makeReadOnly(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:640)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.newBroker(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:171)

Any help Appreciated.

Thanks,
Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `resource-ref` in your `web.xml` with runtime descriptor file (`ibm-web-bnd.xml`) as suggested in [Websphere Datasource with a given JNDI name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167212/how-do-i-connect-to-a-websphere-datasource-with-a-given-jndi-name)

Comment: I was Missing  this in web.xml<resource-ref>
  <res-ref-name>jdbc/Mysource</res-ref-name>
  <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
  <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
  <res-sharing-scope>Unshareable</res-sharing-scope>
 </resource-ref>

Answer (score 1):

Here is Solution of My Problem...

I was Missing this in web.xml

jdbc/Mysource javax.sql.DataSource Container Unshareable